# Continuous Key errors

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

The point of my code is that there is supposed to be an input of yyyymmdd and the answer is to come out as a string, such as if the input was "20191129" then the output would be "November 29th, 2019"

I keep getting random "key error '0'" in my code however and I don't see why that is
Here is my code:

```
def format_date(date):
year = date[:3]
main_month = date[4:5]
main_day = date[6:]

if main_month <= '01' and main_month >= '12':
    return dic_month[main_month]

if main_day <= '01' and main_day >= '31':
    return dic_day[main_day]

month = dic_month[main_month]
day = dic_day[main_day]

return month + ' ' + day + ' ' + year
```

Here are the dictionaries that i am currently using:

```
dic_month = {'1': 'January', '2': 'February', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May', 
         '6': 'June', '7': 'July', '8': 'August', '9': 'September', '10': 'October',
         '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}

dic_day = {'1': '1st', '2': '2nd', '3': '3rd', '4': '4th', '5': '5th', '6': '6th', '7': '7th',
           '8': '8th', '9': '9th', '10': '10th', '11': '11th', '12': '12th', '13': '13th', '14': '14th',
           '15': '15th', '16': '16th', '17': '17th', '18': '18th', '19': '19th', '20': '20th', '21': '21st',
           '22': '22nd', '23': '23rd', '24': '24th', '25': '25th', '26': '26th', '27': '27th', '28': '28th',
           '29': '29th', '30': '30th', '31': '31st',}
```

Please help

Comment: What's the exact error? And note how none of your dictionaries have a 0 key.

Comment: You should fix the indentation in your code example.

Comment: Also note, it would be much easier to do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/1bbcbea9ed7ba5e66723d838900cc99b) instead of using `dict_day`.

Comment: `date[6:]`? We cannot see `date`.

Comment: Your slices are wrong - `year` is 3 characters, `main_month` and `main_day` are a single character each.  Once you fix that, it's still going to fail fairly often, because your dictionary keys don't contain the leading zero on the first nine values.

Answer (score 0):

So many errors...

```
dic_month = {'1': 'January', '2': 'February', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May', 
         '6': 'June', '7': 'July', '8': 'August', '9': 'September', '10': 'October',
         '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}

dic_day = {'1': '1st', '2': '2nd', '3': '3rd', '4': '4th', '5': '5th', '6': '6th', '7': '7th',
           '8': '8th', '9': '9th', '10': '10th', '11': '11th', '12': '12th', '13': '13th', '14': '14th',
           '15': '15th', '16': '16th', '17': '17th', '18': '18th', '19': '19th', '20': '20th', '21': '21st',
           '22': '22nd', '23': '23rd', '24': '24th', '25': '25th', '26': '26th', '27': '27th', '28': '28th',
           '29': '29th', '30': '30th', '31': '31st',}

def format_date(date):
    year = date[:4]
    main_month = date[4:6]
    main_day = date[6:]

    if int(main_month) < 1 or int(main_month) > 12:
        return 'Wrong month'

    if int(main_day) < 1 or int(main_day) > 31:
        return 'Wrong day'

    month = dic_month[main_month]
    day = dic_day[main_day]

    return month + ' ' + day + ' ' + year


print(format_date('20190029')) # 'Wrong month'
print(format_date('20191129')) # 'November 29th 2019'
```